# IEEE citation style word 2016: is automatic reordering possible, and if so how?

Tags: microsoft-word, citations, bibliography

I'm currently working on my thesis in Word 2016 for Windows 10. I'm required to use the IEEE citation style and I want to have my bibliography ordered based on the order with which citations appear in the text.

Therefore, the first citation made in the text should always be labelled [1] - because if I have a citation (X) labelled [1] and I insert a new citation (Y) above it, the (Y) will become [1], and (X) will be updated to [2]. The relevant reordering should also in the Bibliography section.

I've been trying to solve this for a few hours. MS Word 2016 comes with an IEEE citation style but it does not do this.

I downloaded 'IEEE Reference Order' from BibWord at https://bibword.codeplex.com/releases/view/19764
because I thought it was what I needed, but after installing it, I realised it only formats the bibliography slightly differently - unless I'm doing something wrong.

So onto my questions:
1. Is this possible using only Word 2016 + plugins? And if so what am I doing wrong?
2. If this is impossible without using some sort of custom software what options do I have?

Additionally, I'm aware of the question at:
https://superuser.com/questions/1050384/ms-word-2013-ieee-citation-reference-number-order
but it seems to be addressing reordering of multiple numbers within a single set of brackets, rather than what I'm asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Embarrassingly, this was completely my error. The original IEEE format provided in MS-Word 2016 does what I want. I didn't notice because I hadn't used many citations and I had cited works earlier, in other parts of the document that I wasn't considering.

Its possible that IEEE (Word) didn't fit the basic requirements in the past and does now, but it is currently sufficient. This is the reason why the IEEE_Reference version downloaded from BibWord did the same thing - they are essentially the same.